# Calculating list size from original and altered average when x is removed.

Tags: linear-algebra, average, median

The average of x number of values is 66, and when a certain 77 is removed from these values, the average drops to 62. Find x, or the number of values that when averaged give 66, and when 77 is removed from the list x, the new average is 62. What is x, no need to find the values.

Comment: Hint: how do you find averages?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Let the sum of $x$ values be $S$. Then the average is
$$\frac{S}{x} = 66.$$
That if $77$ is deducted the new average is $62$ means
$$\frac{S-77}{x-1} = 62.$$
Combining these two equations yields
$$\frac{4x-15}{x-1}=0.$$
From here we can say that $x\neq 1$ and $x$ is not an integer.